# Check whether a page contains a text but an exact text

Tags: java, selenium, selenium-webdriver

I am using Selenium Java WebDriver. I am trying to check is some text is present in a page.

I am doing this:

```
assertTrue(driver.getPageSource().contains("Hello World"));
```

BUT I just realize that in my page could the text "Hello World 2" be also present. In this case the method above would return True but it should be actually False.
So I need a similar method that checks whether the exact text "Hello World" is present.

Does anybody know something that I could do?

```
<div class="x-grid3-cell-inner x-grid3-col-roles" ext:qtip=
"CAD-Approver">CAD-Approver<input type="hidden" name=
"ap20hiddenRoleNames" value=
"CAD-APPROVER,"></div>
```

I need to find the text = CAD-Approver

Thanks a lot
Pablo

Comment: `assertTrue(driver.getPageSource().contains("Hello World 2") == false);` something like this?

Comment: Could you explain more precisely what the conditions are ? Because if "Hello World 2" is present, the exact word "Hello World" is also present, just followed by something else. Your question is not really clear. What are your words delimited by ?

Comment: Better to do using java .equals() function.

Comment: Can the text be anywhere or is it possible to be more precise by searching (not with pagesource, which is a string containing everything)?

Comment: If you need to check "Hello World" alone, then why don't you try String equals() ? . That means your whole page source contains only "Hello World". Is that what you were looking for?

Comment: @FlorentBayle "Hello World 2" was just an example. Imagine that I want to check whether the word "tennis" is present, but it would be also possible that the word "tabletennis" is present. If only "tabletennis is present my method described before would return True and it should return False. I think the question is clear asked

Comment: @pablocasanovas So, maybe you can use a regexp with [word boundaries](http://www.regular-expressions.info/wordboundaries.html), something like "\btennis\b".

Comment: The thing is that I can not locate the element using ID because I don't have any ID. I only have the name of the class (which is also the name of other elements' class). I have tried to locate the element by.class using many different ways but I was unable to do it and thats why asked if there is any method similiar to pagesource and contains that I could use to find exact texts

Answer (score 1):

Instead of checking the whole page source (which could be a lot!) why don't you narrow down your criteria by finding the text in a web element (e.g. `<text id="text-Hello-World">`) and then search on that?

e.g.

```
String text =  webDriver.findElement(by.Id("text-Hello-World")).getText();
assertTrue(text.equals("Hello World"));
```

Here is a quick little guide to be able to narrow down your search similar to my example:
https://loadfocus.com/blog/2013/09/how-to-locate-web-elements-with-selenium-webdriver/

Note: I don't know Java so that might not compile!

Update:

There are multiple ways of doing this:

```
List<WebElement> elements = webDriver.findElements(by.tagName("div"));
for(Iterator<WebElement> i = elements.iterator(); i.hasNext(); ) {

    string text = i.getText();

    if(text.equals("CAD-Approver"))
    {
     //Do something
    }
}
```

Or you could use a XPath lookup, e.g. `//div[contains(.,'CAD-APPROVER')]`

Comment: Here text is not variable of type string so this line will not work..assertTrue(text.equals("Hello World"));

Comment: @HelpingHands Like i said, I don't know Java, updated my answer

Comment: I already think about it, but the thing is that I can no locate the element since I don't have an ID, I only have a class and I am unable to locate it.
I edit my question with part of the html code

Comment: @pablocasanovas Post the HTML in your original question, you will always be able to locate something.

Comment: Does anybody know what ext:qtip means? (see in the HTML code)

Answer (score 0):

Use .**equals()** java function to compare your strings :

```
String text1 =  webDriver.findElement(by.Id("your text id")).getText();

String text2 = "hello world"

if(text1.equals(text2))
{

   //true
}
else
{
   //false

}
```

So as per above example store your predefined string in variable **text2** and then match it with **text1** value.